# Firefox xul browser doesn't have a page title

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

Firefox browser element does not return page title when tabs are loaded from previous session. 
The code I use:

```
var browsers = gBrowser.browsers;
for (var i = 0, len = browsers.length; i < len; i++) {
    dump('page title #1: ' + browsers[i].contentTitle + '\n'); // here I get no title
    dump('page title #2: ' + browsers[i].contentDocument.title + '\n'); // nothing here
    dump('url: ' + browsers[i].contentDocument.location + '\n'); // url is fully loaded here 
}
```

So the question is: how do I get the page title? Pages start loading when I activate the tab. But page title is shown in the tab list right after the browser starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the pages are really *not* restored. The tabs have `about:blank` loaded into them and the real page only starts loading when the user goes to the tab. So `contentDocument.title` cannot have any meaningful value.

What you apparently want is the title displayed on the tab - it doesn't reflect what is loaded into the tab, it's rather something remembered from the previous session. So you should actually get the tab title, something like this:

```
var tabs = gBrowser.tabs;
for (var i = 0, len = tabs.length; i < len; i++) {
    dump('page title: ' + tabs[i].label + '\n');
}
```